# How to use variables in Wscript.Shell + cmd.exe?

Tags: excel, vba, cmd, wsh

I'm trying to substitute variables to path in a wsh.run command (it should launch a batch file), but I got an error in the dos console: "The file name, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect".

Here the code that works:

```
Sub TestDos()
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim fBatFile As String
Dim ErrorCode As Integer
Dim wkPath As String
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

wkPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
fBatFile = wkPath & "\run.bat"

ErrorCode = wsh.Run("cmd.exe /c cd /d G:\Projects && G:\Projects\run.bat", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
Debug.Print ErrorCode

End Sub
```

I tried with:

```
ErrorCode = wsh.Run("cmd.exe /c cd /d wkPath && fBatFile", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
```

Or:

```
ErrorCode = wsh.Run("cmd.exe /K cd /d " & wkPath & fBatFile & "", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
```

but it doesn't work.
Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: And the Excel file has actually been saved once?

Comment: Yes, certainly.

Comment: hi. fBatFile already includes the path.  remove the wkPath and should work `ErrorCode = wsh.Run("cmd.exe /K cd /d " & fBatFile & "", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)`

Comment: Maybe `ErrorCode = wsh.Run("cmd.exe /c cd /d """ & wkPath & "" && "" & fBatFile"", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)` works - haven't had a chance to double check the escapes.

Comment: @Luis Curado - It doesn't work. I got the same error.

Comment: @notjustme - Unfortunately, I got a "Compile error: Needed expression" (I don't know the exact error in English).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

> ErrorCode = wsh.Run("cmd.exe /c cd /d " & wkPath & " && " & fBatFile,
>   windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

I can't find a clear webpage that explain when and how we need
'&' and "". 
The official documentation is very obscure for me.

Anyway, even this time, it's done!

P.S.: If I use "cmd.exe /k" (I hold the dos console open), instead of '/c', the VBA Editor give me a "Overflow" error. Fortunately, I needed to close the dos console at the end of the batch file.